# Как узнать, в каком потоке выполняется код

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Есть код:

```
Thread newClient = new Thread(StartProcessing);
newClient.IsBackground = true; 
newClient.Start();
```

В нем выполняется функция. Потоку можно задать имя - номер клиента.

Как получить уже внутри функции `StartProcessing` имя текущего потока?

Comment: вам требуется использовать именно string как идентификатор потока? просто у каждого потока есть свой ID (получить можно так Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId). его недостаточно?

Comment: В имени потока я буду держать идентификатор клиента, поэтому не подойдет. Спасибо

Comment: в ваш код перед `newClient.Start()` надо добавить `newClient.Name = "имя";` -- посмотрите мой ответ ниже.

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте использовать статическое свойство CurrentThread класса Thread - оно представляет выполняющийся в данный момент поток. Например:

```
public static void StartProcessing()
{
    // your code
    lock(_lockObj)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[GetCurrentThreadId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683183%28VS.85%29.aspx) - ID текущего потока.

Для старых версий .NET лучше использовать [System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.managedthreadid.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Для получение номера потока можно использовать
`Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId` или `Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId`

Если в поток надо передать какие-то данные, то можно использовать
`Thread.SetData` и `Thread.GetData`, а также  класс `ThreadLocal`.

Если требуется просто имя, то так:

```
using System.Threading;

var t = new Thread(() => { 
    Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.Name);   // выводит 123
});
t.Name = "123";
t.Start();
```